# ZoomIN to Feature with ol3

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs, wfs-t

I have a requirement, upon user action I need to zoomin to the polygon/feature on layer. To achieve this

1. Getting the feature object based on unique Id by using
       wfs?request=GetFeature
2. Getting required feature as expected

   ```
   {"type":"Feature","id":"SEARCH.fid--2a37c556_1505cda2d3b_1593","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[3400.95051588509,4083.02548123558],[3502.22770354563,3981.74829357504],[3598.40160615068,4077.87129986026],[3498.61223022689,4180.68719557739],[3400.95051588509,4083.02548123558]]]},"geometry_name":"GEOM","properties":{"LAYER":"CAGE_INFO","TAG":"7234","NUMBER":"000108"}}
   ```
3. Now, I used the below to options and unsuccessful with the both

   ```
   map.getView().fit(feature.geometry.coordinates,map.getSize()); 
   map.getView().fit(feature.geometry,map.getSize());
   ```

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

**I guess you are using an older version of ol3.** 
If this is true:
This function of Openlayers accepts an extent (first argument) and not a geometry or an array of coordinates.
Try to make up the extent of your geometry.

This should be an array of four coords --> [xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax].

And then pass this extent as the first argument of the function. 
like so:

```
var extent = [xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax];
map.getView().fit(extent ,map.getSize());
```

With the latest versions of OL3 (maybe 3.8 and above but not sure)
map.getView().fit should accept a geometry as well.
Try to use the extent of geometry in any case. It should solve the problem.